# Toggle view of modal button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following modal dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#addLocation" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 820,
        width: 550,
        buttons: {
            "Add Location": function() {
                document.forms['mapform'].submitted.value='1';
                document.forms["mapform"].submit();
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
});
});
```

How can I toggle the 'Add Location' button? I want it to display only when a certain button within the dialog is clicked.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. hide you add location button as soon as dialog is shown on screen. call this after the dialog open command

   ```
   $("button[value='Add Location']").hide();
   ```
2. Then add event to the desired button that will toggle the add location button

   ```
   $("buttonid or any selector").click(function(){
   $("button[value='Add Location']").show();
   });
   ```